# Gherkin steps of called feature file are not shown in cucumber parallel run report when showAllSteps: false

Tags: karate

We are using the report verbosity option available in [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity)

I have a MarketingPreferenceTest.feature calling BBB.feature.

The features are as below:

MarketingPreferenceTest.feature

```
Background:
    * url Url
    * table credentials
        |Email  |Password|
        |'aaa@test.com'|'test1234'|
    * def result = karate.callSingle('classpath:resources/BBB.feature',credentials)

Scenario Outline: Get MS
    Given path 'abc'        
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

BBB.feature:

```
Background:
        * configure retry = { count: 5, interval: 1000 }
        * configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        * url authenticationUrl

    Scenario: Login
        Given path 'login'
        And request { email: '#(Email)' , password: '#(Password)' }
        And retry until responseStatus == 200 && response.loginResponse.loggedIn == true
        When method post
```

My karate.config has

```
karate.configure('report', { showLog: true, showAllSteps: false } );
```

When i run the tests in parallel, i want to see all the Given-When-Then's printed in my cucumber report from BBB.feature. How do i achieve it ?

The cucumber report is shown below which doesn't have step definitions from BBB.feature :

Expected Result: Would like to see the Steps of BBB.feature in my report marked in a rectangle box below

[image: Cucmber Report]

Comment: really confusing question, I don't understand what is needed. please follow this process if you really want some help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas: I have amended my question to make it more clearer, please let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't help, maybe others will have the patience to figure this out without a full working example

Comment: A full working example can be found in https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/712. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the step involving a `callSingle` use a Gherkin keyword:

```
When def result = karate.callSingle('classpath:resources/BBB.feature',credentials)
```